# Trouble integrating Heyzap ads into my Unity application

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, ads, heyzap

As the title says, I'm trying to add the ad wrapper to my project, but I am running into some problems:

- Whenever I run the mediation suite, the *Heyzap* and *Heyzap Cross Promo* networks are fully integrated, with all options ticked. However, if I try to fetch any type of add it will give me a NO_FILL error and I am unable to show it.
- Upon initialising the ad networks, the do become initialised properly so that is fine.
- However if I try and show an ad, say *interstitial*, it will completely fail.

I have checked out the example application Heyzap has put up [here](https://github.com/Heyzap/unity-example-app) and it works perfectly. I even tried putting that into my own project, not changing anything and I got the same problems.

Here is the class I have written:

```
using Heyzap;
using UnityEngine;

public static class AdManager {
    public static void InitialiseAdNetwork() 
    {
        HeyzapAds.NetworkCallbackListener networkCallbackListener = delegate(string network, string callback) {
            Debug.Log("The " + network + " network has been " + callback);
        };
        HeyzapAds.SetNetworkCallbackListener(networkCallbackListener);
        HeyzapAds.Start("myID", HeyzapAds.FLAG_DISABLE_AUTOMATIC_FETCHING);

        HZInterstitialAd.SetDisplayListener(delegate(string adState, string adTag) {
            Debug.Log("INTERSTITIAL: " + adState + " Tag : " + adTag);
        });
        HZIncentivizedAd.SetDisplayListener(delegate(string adState, string adTag) {
            Debug.Log("INCENTIVIZED: " + adState + " Tag : " + adTag);
        });
    } 
    public static void ShowMediationSuite()
    {
        HeyzapAds.ShowMediationTestSuite();
    }

    public static void ShowInterstitialAd() 
    {
        HZInterstitialAd.Fetch();
    }
}
```

Can anyone see something I have done wrong? Because I cannot.

Comment: Same Problem  and cant find any solution 
Are You fix this issue ??

Answer (score 0):

From your code it looks to me that you are not calling to show the AD, but just fetch the AD. For an interstitial AD, you need to call the following line:

```
HZInterstitialAd.Show ();
```

You will only be able to show the AD after a Fetch () call has completed. You can find out when Fetch () has completed successfully by either (1) setting up your delegates to check for it or (2) checking if an AD is available using a method such as HZInterstitialAd.IsAvailable ().

Method (1) - Shows AD immediately after Fetch () has completed - note that this is specific for HeyZap Interstitial ADs and would not work for other AD types (video, etc) or for non-HeyZap networks if you are using mediation:

```
HZInterstitialAd.SetDisplayListener(delegate(string adState, string adTag) {
    Debug.Log("INTERSTITIAL: " + adState + " Tag : " + adTag);

    if ( adState.Equals("available") ) {
        HZInterstitialAd.Show ();
    }
});
```

Method (2) - How you do this method really depends on your architecture. For example, you might add a Try method to your AdManager and have the caller decide what to do if an AD is not ready:

```
public static bool TryShowInterstitialAd() 
{
    if (HZInterstitialAd.IsAvailable ()) {
        HZInterstitialAd.Show ();
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```